# Maintaining source string format when reading a date-time from a JSON path and writing it to another file

Tags: c#, json.net

How can I have Newtonsoft.Json read the value of a path without converting or otherwise meddling with values?

This code

```
jsonObject.SelectToken("path.to.nested.value").ToString()
```

Returns this string

```
03/07/2019 00:02:12
```

From this string in the JSON document

```
2019-07-03T00:02:12.1542739Z
```

It's lost its original formatting, ISO 8601 in this case.

I would like all values to come through as strings, verbatim. I'm writing code to reshape JSON into other formats and I don't want to effect the values as they pass through my .NET code.

What do I need to change? I am not wedded to Newtonsoft.Json btw.

Comment: Do not do a `ToString` directly. Store the result in `JToken`, then use `SerializeObject` and pass serialization options that will keep your date as is.

Comment: You can provide a `DateFormatString` in the `JsonSerializerSettings` options.

Comment: I think the gotcha here is that since Json.net reads *a string* that *looks like* a Date, it interprets it as a Date, and thus all kinds of (re)formatting kicks in. I guess the question is how to avoid this interpretation and access the raw string without change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I think.

```
jsonObject.SelectToken(path).ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

The other options were to supply nothing or this.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented
```

Which is strange logic in this API as you'd think `None` means not indented but it means not ... I don't know. Hang on....

Okay so `None` or `Indented` returns

```
"2019-07-03T00:02:12.1542739Z"
```

(including quotes) but using the overload taking no parameters returns

```
03/07/2019 00:02:12
```

That's an odd API design ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Here's a screenshot which shows really simple repro code.

[image: Screenshot of code and variable inspectors]

Comment: The reason the API behaves like this is that `JValue.ToString()` returns the `ToString()` of the internal value, which is already interpreted as a DateTime value. The overloads with `Formatting` parameters tries to reserialize the `JToken` into json.

Comment: Thanks that explains it. The overload should have been given a different name as this behaviour is unexpected. You'd expect the parameterless one to act like `Formatting.None`.